# Python Regular Expression with Tab and Character separated

Tags: regex, python-2.7

I'm trying to find a pattern which has state (divided by space in between) and then starting three of zipcode ( each divided by space) but space between state and zipcode is separated by tab. I want to find this pattern and return a boolean if it exists. How should I write a regular expression for this?

Eg: N Y   1 0 0

when I tried

```
re.[any method]([A-Z]\s[A-Z]\t[0-9]\s[0-9]\s[0-9])
```

it didn't give me any value back.

Update:

I want to extract value between two key values which have pattern like [All Capitals]: [Some text] [All Capitals]: If I want to extract some text, how can I do that using Reg expressions. Thanks.

Eg: key1: some random text \n key2: some random text 2 \n key1: some random text 3

How can extract the values of key1 and store it as dictionary? From the above example, we have two value for key1 and 1 value for key2.

Comment: It is `\s` not `/s`. You might want to use raw string literals.

Comment: I changed and tried again, but no return value. Here is what I wanted to find is this pattern N[space]Y[tab]1[space]0[space]0[\n]. If it finds this pattern, then it should return true. Thanks Sebastian.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
import re

text = "N Y 1 0 0"

match = re.search("([A-Za-z] [A-Za-z]\t\d \d \d)", text)
if match:
    print (match.group(1))
```

Just looking as was described, letter, space, letter, tab, number, space, number, space, number.

UPDATE:
If you'd like more data past the numbers, simply add that in the regex:

```
text = "N Y 1 0 0 I WANT IT ALL!!!"

([A-Za-z] [A-Za-z]\t\d \d \d.*)
```

.* means .. well, pretty much everything.  Just change the .* around to whatever you'd like to capture, perhaps more \d or certain other patterns.

Comment: Thanks it worked. But if it has more text after 1 0 0 [some text]. How can I get this text value?